# Zeppelin 0.8 java.io.InvalidClassException on EMR-5.21.0 (+ Spark 2.4.0)

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

Here is a bug I'm getting when trying to read *json* file from AWS S3 with an emr cluster having the following setup: EMR-5.21.0, Spark 2.4.0 and Zeppelin 0.8.0

`java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.commons.lang3.time.FastDateParser; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 2, local class serialVersionUID = 3`

I'm not loading any other external dependency which may implicitly import this class (only spark classes)
Do you have any idea about what may cause this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if caused by this but Spark 2.4.0 support was added to Zeppelin 0.8.1 so not expected to work in 0.8.0 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-3810

Comment: I think that this is related to zeppelin 0.8 and AWS EMR. The same problem occurs with spark 2.3.x. And on AWS EMR zeppelin 0.8.1 isn't yet available.